# How to have control of printing every element of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, database, arrays

I want to be able to have control of what I print in this array. So far this is what I have:

```
<?php
/* DB CONNECTION */
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME . '', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
  $sql = 'SELECT nombre,categoria,descripcion FROM equipos ORDER BY nombre ASC';
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}

/*FETCH ARRAY */
$equipos = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  $equipos[] = $row['nombre'];
  $equipos[] = $row['categoria'];
  $equipos[] = $row['descripcion'];
}
?>       
<?php
/* PRINT ARRAY */
foreach($equipos as $equipo): ?>
  <p><?php
  echo htmlspecialchars($equipo);
?></p>
<?php
endforeach; 
?>
```

My results are:

```
Value1
value2
Value3

etc.
```

I want to be able to print something like:

```
Value1, Value2, Value3
Value4, Value5, Value6
```

There's must be a practical easier way.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want but my shoot in the dark
Note the **right** way of connecting to PDO

```
<?php

$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $opt);

$sql    = 'SELECT nombre,categoria,descripcion FROM equipos ORDER BY nombre ASC';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$data   = $result->fetchAll();
?>
```

Now in the `$data` variable you have an array of all the rows, each contains an array with selected fields. Thus you have a control over them via field names:

```
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
  <p>
    <?=htmlspecialchars($row['nombre'])?>,
    <?=htmlspecialchars($row['categoria'])?>,
    <?=htmlspecialchars($row['descripcion'])?>
  </p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I just tried this option but doesn't print any values, only the commas.

Comment: what if without htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score -1):

instead of using the foreach statement use the

```
for(var i = 0;i<(sizeof($equipos);i++)
{
 echo htmlspecialchars($equipo[i]);
}
```

Comment: `.length` isn't a php function or array attribute. This won't work.

Comment: sorry it was sizeof miscorected